# import error; no module named Quandl

Tags: python-2.7, importerror, quandl

I am am trying to run the Quandl module on a virtualenv which I have uninstalled packages only pandas and then Quandl,

I am running Python 2.7.10 - I have uninstalled all other python versions, but its still giving me the issue of 'ImportError: No module named Quandl'. Do you know what might be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Post your code please, most importantly the import.  I assumed a problem but could be more sure with a sample

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try with lower case, import is case sensitive and it's as below:

```
import quandl
```

Did you install with pip?  If so ensure quandl is among the listed installed modules with

```
pip list
```

Otherwise try

```
help('modules')
```

To make sure it was installed properly.  If you don't see quandl listed , try to reinstall.

Comment: `import quandl` (all lower case)

Comment: The answer was to use lowercase for "Q", strangely the tutorial on youtube could run it with a capital "Q". Thanks!

Comment: It used to be uppercase "Q", I think they must have changed it recently, since we ran into the same issue.

Comment: For me too, I had to write it with lowercase in my script even though at the project interpreter on Pycharm is written with upper case...(??)

Answer (score 12):

Use below syntax all in lower case

> **import quandl**

Comment: This worked for me! The problem that i had was, i managed to install to the Quandl package but i imported it as 'Quandle'. pycharm was unable to identify that. so once i changed Quandl to quandl, The problem got solved itself

Answer (score 4):

If the solutions above is not working for you (it means you are using python 3), do the following (on Linux);

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then do ;

```
pip3 install quandl
```

you should be able to import and use quandl now

Answer (score 1):

check whether it exists with the installed modules by typing

> pip list

in the command prompt and if there is no module with the name quandl then type

> pip install quandl

in  the command prompt . Worked for me in the jupyter

Answer (score 0):

I am following a Youtube tutorial where they use 'Quandl'. It should be quandl. Change it and it won't throw error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a related issue with the capitalisation of "Q" in Pycharm IDE (Quandl 3.0.1):

```
import quandl as q
```

The above will correctly import however auto-completion will not function.

```
import Quandl as q
```

The above will not import but will allow auto-completion.

My solution is to use autocomplete when working and then comment out the second import for running.

```
import quandl as q
#import Quandl as q
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by installing the below one:

```
conda install -c dhirschfeld quandl=3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. install quandl for version 3.1.0
2. Check package path where you installed, make sure it's name is quandl not Quandl (my previous name is Quandl, so when I use `import quandl`, it always said "`no module named quandl`")
3. If your package's name is Quandl, delete it and reinstall it. (I use anaconda to install my package, it's covenient!)

Answer (score 0):

With Anaconda\Jupyter notebook go to the install directory (C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3) where <USER_NAME> is your logged in Username. Then execute in command prompt:

1. python -m pip install Quandl
2. import quandl

Answer (score 0):

If someone running Jupyter image on docker and facing the same issue,
 [you can open terminal in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRh6j.png)

and then type

```
pip install quandl
```

it will install the quandl where jupyter kernelspec list points.
then import as

```
import quandl
```

> (q lowercase)

I did not find this solution anywhere else hence mentioned this

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to make it work. Installed quandl through Anaconda Powershell Prompt (not the regular Anaconda Prompt). It depreciated some of my libraries, but finally it is working! Spent 1.5 days to fix this!! Thanks. Original post: [Quandl not working in Jupyter Notebook (but working at command-prompt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58543374/quandl-not-working-in-jupyter-notebook-but-working-at-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

quandl has now changed, you require an api key, go the site and register your email.

import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'your_api_key_here'
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error message ' ImportError: No module named Quandl ' so what i did was to just change it to

```
import quandl
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions listed here worked for me.  I ended up installing it from Jupyter Notebook itself.

```
import sys

!{sys.executable} -m pip install quandl

import quandl
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the quandl module is present with "Quandl" in following location
C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Quandl.

But the scripts from Quandl refer to quandl in import statements. 
So, renaming folder Quandl to quandl worked for me.

New path:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages**quandl**".