# Problems importing quandl module

Tags: python, pip, quandl

I am trying to create a Data Science project using some Quandl dataset, but am receiving an error on import.

As i know quandl should be imported all in lowercase, as the documentation states [here](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426196/import-error-no-module-named-quandl), my import goes as follows:

```py
import quandl
```

Error:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quandl'
```

I installed quandl using `pip install quandl`. My pip list output is:

```
Package         Version
--------------- ---------
asn1crypto      0.24.0
certifi         2019.6.16
cffi            1.12.3
chardet         3.0.4
cryptography    2.7
idna            2.8
inflection      0.3.1
more-itertools  5.0.0
ndg-httpsclient 0.5.1
numpy           1.16.4
pandas          0.24.2
pip             19.1.1
pyasn1          0.4.5
pycparser       2.19
pyOpenSSL       19.0.0
python-dateutil 2.8.0
pytz            2019.1
Quandl          3.4.8
requests        2.22.0
setuptools      41.0.1
six             1.12.0
urllib3         1.25.3
wheel           0.33.4
wincertstore    0.2
```

I don't have pip3, as I installed Python through my Anaconda installation. I am running a Jupyter Notebook in a virtual environment I created just for this project. Just so you know, `python --version` output is:

```
Python 3.7.3
```

The strange part occurs when i try running a one line python script with `import quandl`. This time the program runs without errors, which means that the cause of the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quandl'` is the jupyter notebook, which is not being able to properly find the quandl module.

As a last resource, I tried installing quandl inside jupyter notebook:

```py
!pip install quandl
import quandl
```

Output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: quandl in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (3.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.14 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (19.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: inflection>=0.3.1 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools<=5.0.0 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (0.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ndg-httpsclient in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.7.0 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from quandl) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.14->quandl) (2019.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.3 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from pyOpenSSL->quandl) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.7.0->quandl) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.7.0->quandl) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.7.0->quandl) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.7.0->quandl) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.3->pyOpenSSL->quandl) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.3->pyOpenSSL->quandl) (1.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\not_me\.conda\envs\quant\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.3->pyOpenSSL->quandl) (2.19)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-614264e6071a> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install quandl')
----> 3 import quandl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quandl'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Jupyter was not properly recognizing my virtual environment. I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook), the workaround is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 install quandl` . It usually works for Python 3.x

Comment: My Python was installed in my Anaconda installation, hence I don't have pip3 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it by running

```
!pip install quandl
```

In a cell in a Jupyter notebook. If you have things set up correctly, there's a chance that will be the same version of pip you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip using the module syntax rather than the standalone CLI for when you want to make sure you are using the version of `pip` associated with that interpreter.

`python -m pip install quandl`

Or, since you are using Conda, you could also try installing `quandl` with the `conda` CLI.

`conda install quandl` (or whatever the package's name is for `conda`).