# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'

Tags: python, quandl

Whenever I try to import quandl

```
import quandl
```

this error appears

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quandl'

although I checked it was installed using

```
pip list
```

and Quandl 3.5.2 was installed

Comment: Your question has already answered here. [import-error-no-module-named-quandl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426196/import-error-no-module-named-quandl)

Comment: install with `pip3 install modulename`, and check with `pip3 list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pip install package_name to target your 2.x python use: `pip install package_name`

To pip install package_name to target your 3.x python use: `pip3 install package_name`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of this gonna help:

- Check, if you are using virtual environment with installed quandl to run your scratch in your IDE.
- Try `import Quandl`.
- Install `quandl==3.4.8`.
- Install and use quandl without venv.
- Install pandas.
- Install Pillow.

edit.
I've just tried to create new venv with quandl, and everything works.
What I've did:

- `deactivate`,
- `virtualenv new_venv`,
- `source new_venv/bin/activate`,
- `pip install quandl`,
- `python <scratch_dir>`.

Then in PyCharm:

- **Settings > Project:<project_name> > Python Interpreter**,
- expand: *Python Interpreter:*,
- **Show All... > + > Virtualenv Environment**,
- check *Existing environment*,
- choose (should be automatically chosen) new venv in *Interpreter:*.
- In the upper right corner expand menu with your scratch's name,
- choose *Edit Configurations...*,
- choose the venv in **Evironment > Python interpreter:**.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries that are installed using pip 3 will not work in python 2. Libraries installed with pip wont work with python 3. Make sure that you are using the right `pip` or `pip3` instillation technique.